# Oracle Database Block Size

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

One of our Production database has a rather peculiar block size of 16KB. This database was created about 2 years ago and at that time the size of the db was approx 1TB only.
However over the past 2 years the db size has grown to approx 5TB.

The workload is a mix of OLTP (transaction) as well as OLAP (reporting).

This db block size is causing our DB Buffer Pool to be constantly filled up (95%~100% full).
The db uses ASM on Raw Devices.

Is the 16KB db block size sub-optimal?
Can this large block size be adversely impacting our storage sub-system performance?
If so what can be done to remedy the situation?

Noteworthy here is that we do in fact perform huge full table scan for reporting as well as for our application (business logic).
The OLTP nature stems from the fact that our application also has transactional (financial transaction) module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This db block size is causing our DB Buffer Pool to be constantly
>   filled up (95%~100% full)

Your DB Buffer Pool should always be full unless you have recently restarted your server - Oracle will not purge blocks from the cache unless it has to in order to make room for other blocks.

This in itself is not an indication that changing the block size will improve anything. You need to know more about the cache misses.

If the OLTP side of your workload can query any part of your 5TB data, optimizing the buffer pool a little for it will probably not make much difference (but may unnecessarily slow down your big sequential scans that it was presumably optimized for)

On the other hand, if there is a small subset of the data hit regularly, and cache misses for the OLTP workloads can be substantially reduced by reducing the block size (which will depend on whether the reads are really scattered across blocks or not), then perhaps the benefits would be significant.

In the end you will have to test and find out :)

Comment: You are correct. My mistake, i did not put forth my point more clearly. Our Buffer cache is constantly full but what is important to note here is that our average row-length varies between 60B to 220B. Yes monitoring the cache miss will give us a good idea the usefulness of the 16KB block size

Comment: So are there lots of single row queries scattered over the entire data set? A low cache hit ratio on it's own [does not necessarily mean a problem](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:558362403109852::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4973488577582)

Comment: The workload can be summarized as- Large Reads (Indexed and FTS) then Table/view joins and aggregations based on certain filters, this gives us the target data set for the next stage of the application. This next stage is purely oltp in nature with single row reads and writes happening.

Comment: "single row reads and writes" from what percentage of the 5TB - all of it or just a subset?

Comment: The single reads and writes constitute a significantly small portion of our db. most of these tables are iot. However the queries executing the single row reads/writes are pretty complex and perform heavy reads from other tables for checking the business logic conditions before carrying out update/insert on these tables.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, I suggest you go ahead and test with a smaller block size. Be wary of the [possible negative consequences](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:329017235004) as well as the benefits

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I'll try changing the db block size on our test bed and monitor it for a while. If every thing seems fine i'll take this to production. However, could you please elaborate on the "possible negative consequences" some more. The Oracle recommended db block size is 8KB, do you foresee any drastic performance implications of changing the db block size from 16k to 8k

Comment: Did you check the link in my comment?

Comment: My belief is that changing the block size from 16KB to 8KB should have more pros than cons in our environment. Apart from utilizing Buffer Cache more efficiently, the smaller block size will also ensure optimal utilization of our storage subsystem. Random IOPS of a storage subsystem is designed for small chunks of data (4k or 8k), the larger chunk sizes are more efficient for sequential data transfers.